# what am I doing wrong in this equation?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, equation

I am trying to make a function that if a point is outside a certain circle, the point move to the point where the line passing by the center of the circle and the point collide. the code:

```
def inside_circle(self, pos):
    if ((pos[0]-self.pos[0])**2 + (pos[1]-self.pos[1])**2) <= teleport_range**2:
        return "inside"#pos
    else:
        pente = (pos[1]-self.pos[1])/(pos[0]-self.pos[0])
        origine = pos[1]-pente*pos[0]
        A = pente**2 + 1
        B = 2 * -self.pos[0] + (origine+self.pos[1])*pente*2
        C = self.pos[0]**2 + (origine+self.pos[1])**2 - teleport_range**2
        if pos[0] > self.pos[0]:
            X = (-B + math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C))/(2*A)
            Y = pente * X + origine
            return "outside bot"#(X,Y)
        elif pos[0] < self.pos[0]:
            X = (-B - math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C))/(2*A)
            Y = pente * X + origine
            return "outside top"#(X,Y)
```

self.pos is the center of the circle, pos is where the point I wanna check is, both are tuple

pente is the tilt of the line (its in french sorry)

origine is the Y origin of the line (french also)

teleport_range is the radius, being a constant 300

the actual return I want are commented for testing purposes

When I run it, if it is inside the circle, everythings fine but if it is outside, an error show up because it is trying to square root a negative

X = (-B + math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C))/(2*A)
ValueError: math domain error

the square root in the quadratic equation is only negative when there is no collide point between the line and the circle, however, the line pass by the center of the circle and a point, so there should be two collide point.

I know there can be only one collide point when the line is a constant but I will fix that when I understand why (B**2 - 4*A*C) is negative when it shouldnt

I am not good in math, if someone could help me please, also dont hesitate to tell me if the code could be simplified without loosing clarity

thanks :)

Comment: "when it shouldn't" - check your assumptions.

Comment: I don't think anybody is going to want to spend their time deciphering that slew of terribly named variables.

Comment: yes I changed it sorry, forgot some of my variables where in french :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier, shorter, clearer way to get your desired point on the circle.

```
theta = math.atan2(pos[0] - self.pos[0], pos[1] - self.pos[1])
X = self.pos[0] + teleport_range * math.cos(theta)
Y = self.pos[1] + teleport_range * math.sin(theta)
```

This code first finds the angle of inclination of the ray from the circle's center to the point. It then uses that angle to find a point on the circle with the same angle.

Note that this code even works for points inside the circle: it finds the point on the circle with the same angle from the center. If the point is the circle's center, the desired point is ambiguous but the code returns one particular point.

Comment: thanks for that! I was actually working on a similar way of solving the problem with inbuilt function of pygame Vector2 because my previous way is obviously way too complicated for nothing, no need of quadratic equation for that, thanks again :)